# How to Remote Access MySQL 5.6 on OSX

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite, navicat

i have been working this shit whole day but i still can not figure this problem out. Tried too many ways but i almost lost hope. i wish anyone can help me out.

i have a mysql 5.6 install on my mac yosemite and i am pretty sure that

1. [the database instance is running well, i can access from my local and i can also visit from remote via ssh login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZrzh.jpg)
2. [i used brew default install and i checked the my.cnf in my local, there is no sorta bind-address there at all! as i searched my.cnf, i believe there is only one my.cnf and which is taking effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YBdc.jpg)
3. [i granted all privileges to root and remote access for all!]
4. [i disabled fire vault]
   [i disabled fire fire wall]
5. [i don't have any iptable staff... i wish i could install that shoot :P]

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: look at the my.cnf for the bind-address and set to 0.0.0.0 - and restart the db to use all interfaces

Comment: not working Bernd Buffen. But finally i got it out. i will comment down the trick below.

Comment: which error message you get if you try from remote server : mysql -hxx.xx.xx.xx -uroot -p ; where xx is the IP from your mac

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I got this out. Stack Overflow is a miracle... I just got it out after posting my answer...

Great, check brew see what I got for this surprise.
[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeR3t.jpg)
check cat /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.23/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist. Bind address is right there.